# The difference between CREDIT and LOAN

Tags: meaning

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/credit_1?q=credit

**[uncountable, countable] money that you borrow from a bank; a loan
The bank refused further credit to the company.**

According to this definition these are correct.

1 I took out a credit from the bank.

2 I took out credit from the bank.

3 I took out a loan from the bank.

Do you agree that 1 and 2 are correct?

Comment: I don't think that definition is very good, and I am puzzled that it is in that dictionary.  I can't think of a *countable* use of credit with that meaning.

Comment: Most people here speak American English.  The Oxford English dictionary is *British* English.  That's why we think "money that you borrow from a bank" is *different*.

Comment: @stangdon In British English, at least, you can come across usages like 'monies' - ie. separate funds of money; so, a countable use. I can't recall having seen 'credits' in the same sense, but I would understand that similarly.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n We use "monies" in a financial sense too in AmE, but I'm struggling to think of a sentence where I would use "credits" with the meaning given in that dictionary.  The bank extended me credit; I have a line of credit; sure, but never "the bank extended me credits" or whatever.

Comment: @RonJohn Please, how does that work? How is 'money that you borrow from a bank' different in US American, British or any other form of English?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin not being British, and not knowing British colloquialisms, I don't know specifically what Brits say in this situation.  All I know is that 'Muricans wouldn't refer to "money that you borrow from a bank" as *credit*.  They'd call it a loan.

Comment: The link above is a fine example of how dictionaries use definitions that work in grammar, yet say nothing about meaning…

In the context of the Question, The difference between CREDIT and LOAN is almost meaningless.

Either way, if you can justify how the three examples given relate to the linked definition, please do!

Until then, both 'I took out (a) credit from the bank' and even 'I took credit…' are all intelligible but none is idiomatic or grammatical.

'I took (out) a loan from the bank' is your only useful choice, there.

Comment: @RonJohn Who said 'Most people here speak American English. The Oxford English dictionary is British English. That's why we think "money that you borrow from a bank" is different…' was that you? 

Now, you don't know what Brits might say? What changed?

I'd never come across 'Muricans' and if that was a polite term, still I wouldn't how any loan wasn't a form of credit. Can you explain?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin sigh.  Americans can call themselves anything they want.  It's why African-Americans can call themselves N-words.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin and I've never said that Americans and English always use the same words/phrases to mean the same thing.  If you think I did, then *you* misunderstood.

Comment: @RonJohn You did say 'Most people here speak American English. The Oxford English dictionary is British English. That's why we think "money that you borrow from a bank" is different…' which conclusion - sorry - is not justified.

What you might mean by 'I've never said that Americans and English always use the same words/phrases to mean the same thing…' is not clear. Sorry if you thought it was and please either explain it here, or go to Chat!

Answer (score 8):

We don't say "I *took* credit from a bank" - that isn't the correct terminology. Borrowing money from a bank is a 'loan'.

'Credit' is used in different ways:

- You can be *in* credit in a bank account, meaning you have available money that is yours to withdraw.
- You can *have* credit available to you on something like a credit card, which means you may automatically spend up to that amount of money without further approval. The amount you spend then effectively becomes a debt, as you have to pay it off with available funds.

With credit cards - although they may offer you 'credit', the moment you take it, you have 'borrowed' on your card. They don't normally call it a loan because it is open-ended, up to your pre-approved credit limit. Loans are agreed at a fixed amount.

There are other uses of the word 'credit' as well - being "in *good* credit" or having a "good credit rating" means that your history of paying debts and loans is good and this often means you have greater borrowing power.

Comment: OK. But the dictionary says "[uncountable, countable] money that you borrow from a bank; a loan. The bank refused further credit to the company." If this is correct "The bank refused further credit to the company.", why is this not correct "The bank refused to give further credit to the company."?

Comment: 'Further credit' means capacity for a loan. When a bank offers it to you, it's credit; when you take it, it's a loan. So it sounds like they loaned them a set amount, but wouldn't offer them 'further credit', or additional borrowing.

Comment: Let me approach the matter from purely collocational perspective. Am I correct in thinking that "offer/have credit" is a good collocation, "take/give credit" is not used.

Comment: @user1425 Pretty much. 'Give credit' and 'take credit' mean something entirely different in a non-financial setting.

Comment: The "loan" sense of ***credit*** is extended from the underlying literal meaning *reputation for truthfulness, accuracy, or honesty; trustworthiness.* The full OED has it as definition II-9 *Trust or confidence in a customer's ability and intention to pay at some future time, shown by allowing money or goods to be taken or services to be used without immediate payment.* Merchants may ***offer credit** [facilities, terms]*, but ***have credit*** and ***give/take credit*** aren't at all likely with this sense (they'd more likely occur with the senses ***believability*** and ***approval***).

Comment: If my company decides to let a customer have goods without paying for them beforehand, but rather allow them to pay at a later date, or in instalments (UK spelling), I can say my company is **extending** credit to that customer.

Comment: I have never heard "to be in credit" to.

Comment: @lambie if you have money in your bank account, you are in credit. If you go overdrawn, you are in debit.

Comment: Is that Canadian or something? In the US, we say: to have a negative or positive balance in an account....

Comment: The other term would be **[a line of credit](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lineofcredit.asp)**, which is countable, e.g. "The credit report shows three lines of credit: a home equity loan, and two credit cards".

Comment: @Lambie I've never heard it as a Canadian (Toronto) either.

Comment: @Lambie I don't know why you're discussing it, I haven't referred to that expression in my answer.

Comment: @Astralbee I've also never heard "in credit". It seems like you're just extrapolating the opposite of "in debt".

Comment: Yes, you did. You said this: "You can be in credit in a bank account". That is simply not financial Enlglish.

Comment: @lambie learn: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/53891/what-does-it-mean-to-be-in-credit-or-in-debit

Comment: @Astralbee Just as I thought. The OP says "in credit", not the utility (electric) company. They say: account (credit). Someone can have a credit amount in an account in their name. The OP has a account credit. That yes. So, I guess after 35 years of accounting/financial/banking translation into English, I am familiar with the lingo.

Answer (score 4):

Usual usage:

The bank refused to **extend** more or additional credit to the company.
A store **gives you a credit** for a product you return.

The bank had given us a $5,000 loan.

To take out or get or obtain a loan from a bank [loan: a specific amount]

To obtain or get credit from a bank (the idea whereby a bank or other institution or even a store allows you to obtain something with a value at some time in the future without paying for it right away).

- The store **would not return the $100 for the product** I returned, but gave me a $100 credit. That means I can go there and spend that money for a product in the future.

Credit is the idea that you are given permission to borrow from an institution or company. You can be what is called creditworthy and not owe any money at all. But you are seen as being able to borrow money (get a loan), if you need to.

Loan is a set amount the bank or financial institution gives you and you will have to pay back.

to receive a credit of some amount from a store. [can be countable]
to have credit with an institution [uncountable]

Answer (score 0):

Is ‘I took (out) (a) credit from the bank’ literally according to the definition, or your interpretation, or are you saying there is no difference?

Both credit and loan can be either nouns or verbs. Do you mind which we’re looking at here?

When they’re nouns, credit and loan can both be countable, or uncountable. Does that matter here?

Credit is ‘what you borrow from a bank’ only in the tightly restricted sense of ‘I used £XX credit.’ Can you doubt that?

Otherwise credit is not what you actually borrow, but how much you might be able to borrow… as, for instance ‘I have £50,000 credit so I can ask the bank for a loan up to that amount.’

That ‘The bank refused further credit to the company’ does mean ‘the bank refused further loans…’ but the senses are too different. They are so far apart, we might be comparing ‘eating’ and ’food’ or ‘distance’ and ‘travel’ or ‘age’ and ‘time.’